# Позиционирование картинки по центру

Tags: html, css

Добрый день, вопрос простой, на примере ВКОНТАКТЕ, клика на фотку в альбоме своего френда: как реализовать такую же схему: страница на три прокрутки вниз, но когда кликаешь на фотку - кладется полупрозрачный оверлей, на нем размещается полноразмерная фотография, но при этом сам сайт не скроллится вниз-вверх, а скроллится только черно-прозрачный оверлей с фоткой. position fixed для оверлея высота которого несколь ко больше картинки полноразмерной? или как? как создается полупрозрачный оверлей я прекрасно представляю, вопрос именно - как реализовать структуру, что прокрутка только на фотке и ее подложечном черном оверлее, а сама страница не прокручивается?

Comment: ага, спасибо ребят ) jquery - это неспортивно в данном случае ))

Answer (score 1):

Это ответ на вопрос про оверлей...

Например так:

```
<style type="text/css">
html, body, .wrapper {
    padding:0; margin:0; height:100%;
}
.wrapper {
    overflow: auto;
}
.myOverlay {
  left:0; 
  top:0; 
  position: absolute; 
  background:lightgray; 
  z-index: 1000;
  width: 100%; 
  height:100%;
  opacity:0.5;
  filter:alpha(opacity=50);
}
</style>
//=======================
<div class="wrapper">много текста</div>
```

Можно воспользоваться готовыми решениями типа jquery ui

Comment: `overflow:auto` сработает только если содержимое превысит размеры дива

Comment: Лучше вручную  всё прописать, чем целую либу подключать.

Answer (score 1):

```
div {overflow: scroll}
```

Как вариант `overflow-x` или `overflow-y` в зависимости от ваших нужд.